# Read message from multiple service bus topics subscription using logic app

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have scenario that I want to read all messages from all topics a and a specific subscription using azure logic app connector.

Example: topic ATopic, BTopic has a same name "TestSubscription" subscription

Using azure logic app I want to read all topics messages on above "TestSubscription"

[I have mark in read in below image at particular place I want a dynamic topic name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGCcp.png)

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern for scenarios like this is to have a Logic App for each Trigger/Topic/Subscription.

Then these Logic Apps, two in your case, call a third work Logic App which does any real message processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event Grid trigger if you have Service Bus premium, to subscribe to `Microsoft.ServiceBus.ActiveMessagesAvailableWithNoListeners` event. Once the Logic App is triggered, you can then use the Service Bus action to retrieve the actual message and process it.